# Are metal beehive frame spacers allowed in hold luggage when flying from EU to the States?

Tags: usa, luggage, airport-security, hand-luggage

Can I bring beehive frame spacers with me to the USA as hold luggage?

[image]

And on the flights to the USA, are these not allowed as carry on baggage?

Comment: @JoErNanO They appear to be beehive frame spacers (not really sure what that means). I added the link I found from google image search. Not sure if that is too promotional.

Comment: @StrongBad I believe these are elements placed inside artificial bee hives to keep the frames that contain the honeycombs evenly spaced and upright at all times. Without these, the frames might move and trap some bees or keep some combs inaccessible by the bees.

Comment: Why do you want them in your hand luggage?  Are you anticipating bees aboard the plane?

Comment: I do not whant them in hand luggage, I know that will be a big problem, but I was asking if it is allowed to bring a bag with me on the carry on luggage afer I will place this things for bees in hold luggage

Comment: Your question "Can I bring this with me to the USA? **_As hand luggage?_**" Now, your comment: "I do not want them in hand luggage. I will place these things in hold luggage."

Comment: @theonlygusti: the question said "as hold luggage", but several users (including a moderator!) have taken upon themselves to change that to "as hand luggage", with no justification that I can see.

Comment: @Andrej: Why do you think having those things on the _hold_ luggage can influence whether you're allowed to bring a carry-on bag? Are you saying you want to carry the bag with the things through the airport's passenger concourses and then gate-check them as you board the plane? Is there any reason why you would want to do that instead of either checking them at the check-in desk or having them with you in the cabin?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The question specifically included `And on the flights to the USA, are these not allowed as carry on baggage?` since revision 1.

Comment: @JoErNanO: Yes, it seems he's asking about _both_, so editing one of the two questions away changes what he's asking about.

Comment: I was also asking how is the situation about baggae in the cabin, forget about metal stuff for now, because I saw on http://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Free-baggage-rules that is you can not carry anything with you (baggage) in cabin

Comment: @JoErNanO numpty dumpty

Comment: Turns out they're actually a couple metres long each and razor sharp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [TSA webpage](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring) covers things you can bring in your checked and carry on baggage. It is not clear what aspect of the item makes you think it is not allowed. Assuming the object meets the size requirements and is just made out of aluminum there should not be a problem. For example, [saws](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/saws) are allowed in checked baggage, although they *should be sheathed or securely wrapped to prevent injury to baggage handlers and inspectors*.